# How to use abstract factory on interacting widgets

Tags: design-patterns, object-oriented, abstract-factory

## Context

In many GUI frameworks, it is very common that widgets are placed in a container to arrange them visually in a window. For example, in Gtkmm, a window with a label and a button (side by side) will look like this:

```cpp
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    auto app = Gtk::Application::create(argc, argv, "no.abstract.factory");

    // Create widgets to appear in the window:
    Gtk::Label label{"A label"};
    Gtk::Button button{"A button"};

    // Create a container to hold widgets and
    // add widgets inside the container at
    // specific locations. This gives control
    // on where widgets will be located in the
    // window when displayed to users.
    Gtk::Grid container;
    container.attach(label, 0, 0, 1, 1);
    container.attach(button, 1, 0, 1, 1);

    // Create the window and add the container
    // to it:
    Gtk::Window window;
    window.add(container);

    window.show_all();

    return app->run(window);
}
```

To avoid depending too much on the GUI framework, the abstract factory pattern could be used, as described in the book *Design Patterns*, by Gamma and al. Using this pattern, interfaces (or abstract classes) are created to represent the widgets and constructor calls are hidden behind factory:

```cpp
IGUIFactory* factory = new GtkmmGUIFactory();  // Or QtGUIFactory() ...

// Later in the code (we now have no idea what is the
// underlying GUI framework) ...

ILabel* label = factory->CreateLabel();
IButton* button = factory->CreateButton();

// ...
```

With this approach, the application code does not depend on the GUI framework, except for the factory, which means there is minimal work to be done if another GUI framework is to later be adopted.

## Question

In the Gtkmm example above not only are widgets created, but they are also added to a container for arrangement in a window. The container is then itself added to the window.

With the abstract factory patten approach, however, with interfaces hiding away all of the GUI framework's details, how can I actually arrange my widgets in the container? If I create an interface to abstract the container, The call to `Gtk::Grid::attach` will never be accessible because the widgets it takes as its first argument will be of the interface type, not the Gtkmm type. I could also use casting, but that would mean the framework's widget interfaces is derived from publicly and I want to avoid that.

So in this context, how can GUI elements interact with each other once they are created and the GUI handles are lost? For example, how could we re-write the Gtkmm example above but in an abstract way, so as to not depend too much on the framework?

Note: my example is in C++ because it is the language I will ultimately be using, but I don't mind if the answer is not, as long as the answer is clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You solve this with composition, not inheritance (you can even call it a "facade" if you want to). Excuse broken syntax, I haven't written C++ for a while...

```
class IGrid {
  public:
    void attachLabel(ILabel *label, <other parameters>) = 0;
}

class GtkmmGrid : public IGrid {
  public:
    GtkmmGrid(Gtk::Grid underlying) : _underlying(underlying) { }

    void attachLabel(ILabel *label, <other parameters>) {
      _underlying.attach(label, <other parameters>)
    }

  private:
    Gtk::Grid _underlying;
}
```

Next, add `IGrid* createGrid()` to your abstract factory, and you can now do:

```
IGrid *grid = factory->createGrid();
ILabel *label = factory->createLabel();

grid.attachLabel(grid, <other parameters>);
```

In theory, you are now insulated from changes to your GUI framework. In practice, this never happens - your other GUI framework might take different parameters on the `attachLabel` call, or in might not even have the concepts of grids and labels. This to me is a clear case of [YAGNI](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/Yagni.html) - start worrying about this problem when you actually want to support a second GUI framework  and know what the shared abstractions between the two frameworks are. At the moment, you risk writing a lot of code which doesn't actually bring you any value in the long run.

What is even more likely in my experience is that you *never* change to a second GUI framework.

Comment: How does this line work: `_underlying.attach(label, <other parameters>)` with `label` being of type `ILabel`? `Gtk::Grid::attach` needs a Gtkmm type, like `Gtk::Label`.

Comment: The simplest is to downcast, however much you may dislike that as an LSP violation. If you want to avoid it, you need to go to a higher level of abstraction again, build up an abstract model of the GUI and have a way of translating that abstract model into each concrete GUI implementation. I would again say "YAGNI".

Comment: Downcasting is fine in this situation because you don't need to adjust the code every time a new sub-type is added.

Comment: @DanielT. Well, it means if you pass in the wrong type of `ILabel` you get an exception which means you need to handle that somehow, and that's a pain... but I still agree it's the most practical solution to this.

Comment: Think about it though. In this context, in order to pass in the wrong subtype, you would have to be using two different GUI systems at the same time and freely mixing them. In this case, you *want* to get the exception and the only reasonable way to handle it is to change the calling code. There is no notion of "handling" the exception.

Comment: @DanielT., your last comment is what was missing for me, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

> So in this context, how can GUI elements interact with each other once they are created and the GUI handles are lost?

They can't. The 'contract' of an `AbstractGrid` that can attach an `AbstractLabel` essentially states that it can deal with **any** abstract label type.

You could use a generic approach, but that will get very messy, very quickly.

```
class AbstractGrid<LabelType> {
    void attach(LabelType *label) { ... }
}
```

**A different approach:**

Instead of going through a set of abstract interfaces to manipulate the GUI framework, you implement a conceptual UI model. A `GtkmmUI` monitors this model and mirrors it in the actual GUI.

```
class Grid {
    void attach(Label *label) { ... }
    void registerLabelAttachedCallback(LabelAttachedCallback *cb) { ... }
}

class Label {
    string text();
    void registerTextChangedCallback(TextChangedCallback *cb) { ... }
}
```

This is essentially MVVM on a very low level - since it involves detailed UI concepts, such as labels. Of course you can also go for a higher-level model, leaving more decisions to the translation code, or for an analogous approach with an MVU design.

The essential theme of all these options is that you *abstract over the whole UI, not its individual components*. I expect that this will also make it easier to deal with mismatches in different GUI frameworks.

Answer (score 1):

Create an interface to abstract a generic widget of the GUI framework, e.g. `IWidget`.

Then, use composition and store the handle to the actual widget. One idea would be to use precompilation directives to change the type of this handle, if you want to change the GUI engine later.

```
class IWidget {
  public:
    BASE_WIDGET_TYPE* _widgetHandle; // BASE_WIDGET_TYPE is resolved to a concrete 
                                     // base widget type from the GUI engine, in pre-compilation
}
class ILabel : public IWidget {
  ...
}
class IButton : public IWidget {
  ...
}
```

In OP's example, `grid.attach` expects a generic `Gtk::Widget`, so you would write the abstracted method like:

```
class GtkGrid : public IGrid {
  public:
    GtkGrid(Gtk::Grid grid) : _grid(grid) { }
    void Attach(IWidget* widget, <other parameters>);

  private:
    Gtk::Grid _grid;
}

//Implementation
void GtkGrid::Attach(IWidget* widget, <other parameters>) {
  _grid.attach(widget->_widgetHandle, <other parameters>); // No cast required
}
```

Please note that no cast is required here, since the actual base widget type is set during pre-compilation, and can change if needed. This assumes you won't need two GUI engines at the same time, at runtime.